# ListView cutting off data, React Native App

Tags: javascript, react-native, listview

In my React Native app I am printing data saved in database. My problem is that not all of data is printing on screen but cuts off on some point.

```
firebase.database().ref(user.uid).child('plantList').child(keyPlant).on('value', function(snapshot){

        console.log(snapshot.val().namePlant);

        const nameC = snapshot.val().nameC;

        var newData = [...that.state.listViewData]
        newData.push(snapshot)

        that.setState({ listViewData: newData})

    });

...

<ListView
        style={{height:500}}
        enableEmptySections
        dataSource = {this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.listViewData)}
        renderRow={snapshot =>
       <View>           

        <View style={styles.tabHeader}><Text style={styles.textHeader}>Scientific name</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.tabContent}><Text style={styles.textContent}>{snapshot.val().namePlant}</Text></View>

        <View style={styles.tabHeader}><Text style={styles.textHeader}>Common name</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.tabContent}><Text style={styles.textContent}>{snapshot.val().nameC}</Text></View>

...

        </View>
           }
         />
```